# Returning HttpResponse and responding with it in PayPal system

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, paypal

I am new to paypal system and I have big problem catching orderID returning from my server on client side.

I am having this code on server side:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Order/create-paypal-order")]
public async Task<HttpResponse> CreatePayPalOrder(bool debug = false)
{
    var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    request.Prefer("return=representation");
    request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());
    //3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
    HttpResponse response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);
    if (debug)
    {
        var result = response.Result<Order>();
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
        Console.WriteLine("Links:");
        foreach (LinkDescription link in result.Links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
        }
        AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
        Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);
    }

    return response;
}
private static OrderRequest BuildRequestBody()
{
    OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
    {
        CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",

        ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext
        {
            BrandName = "LimitlessSoftTest",
            LandingPage = "BILLING",
            UserAction = "CONTINUE",
            ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
        },
        PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>
        {
            new PurchaseUnitRequest{
                ReferenceId =  "PUHF",
                Description = "Sporting Goods",
                CustomId = "CUST-HighFashions",
                SoftDescriptor = "HighFashions",
                AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown
                {
                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                    Value = "230.00",
                    AmountBreakdown = new AmountBreakdown
                    {
                        ItemTotal = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "180.00"
                        },
                        Shipping = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "30.00"
                        },
                        Handling = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "10.00"
                        },
                        TaxTotal = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "20.00"
                        },
                        ShippingDiscount = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "10.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                    Items = new List<Item>
                {
                    new Item
                    {
                        Name = "T-shirt",
                        Description = "Green XL",
                        Sku = "sku01",
                        UnitAmount = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "90.00"
                        },
                        Tax = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "10.00"
                        },
                        Quantity = "1",
                        Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                    },
                    new Item
                    {
                        Name = "Shoes",
                        Description = "Running, Size 10.5",
                        Sku = "sku02",
                        UnitAmount = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "45.00"
                        },
                        Tax = new Money
                        {
                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                          Value = "5.00"
                        },
                        Quantity = "2",
                        Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                    }
                },
                ShippingDetail = new ShippingDetail
                {
                    Name = new Name
                    {
                        FullName = "John Doe"
                    },
                    AddressPortable = new AddressPortable
                    {
                        AddressLine1 = "123 Townsend St",
                        AddressLine2 = "Floor 6",
                        AdminArea2 = "San Francisco",
                        AdminArea1 = "CA",
                        PostalCode = "94107",
                        CountryCode = "US"
                    }
                }
              }
            }
    };

    return orderRequest;
}
```

And on client side:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AeGBdpKN0NdruKiwvJIiLsHFhqHYQw7oCyo_G1SsgChM_MgnA4ELwvUPxjJRY-GrqXRvTdhvXw-bWPHi&currency=EUR">
</script>

<div id="paypal-button-container" style="text-align: center"></div>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function () {
            return fetch('/Order/create-paypal-order', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                var a = res.json();
                alert("RES:" + a);
                console.log(a);
                return a;
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("DATA: " + data.id);
                return data.id; // Use the key sent by your server's response, ex. 'id' or 'token'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            });
        }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

This is what I am getting when debugging:

[image]

As you can see there is data and ID and everything else (not sure if it needs to be directly in "Headers" but tried manually adding it there too)

And on client side I get error "Expected an order id to be passed". Here is console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All return data needs to be in the body (not headers) of your server's HTTP response, formatted as JSON. You should be able to put the full URL for `/Order/create-paypal-order` in any web browser and see JSON data, with the id key having the orderID value. If you can't see this, your server is returning the wrong data or it is formatted wrong.

You should also debug what your server is returning in the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools, in the Response section of the fetch request to `/Order/create-paypal-order`. This will be formatted as a raw string, if you are indeed returning JSON data that corresponds to your server's `result` object, as you should be.

Comment: I am trying everything I think will solve my problem and doing it for many many hours but I am still not moving a bit...